# svn ignore issue

Tags: svn

I have set the following rule for my project in a specific svn dir (in root before adding new files just a clean checkout):

```
*/bin */obj *.user *.suo
```

After that I have copied some visual studio project. Click-right - Add and now I expect that obj folder or bin to no longer appear...but they appear and are checked as ready to be added.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files have been marked before you set the ignore rule. Just deselect them manually and the rule should apply on next commit.